# I am trying to get this code to copy swatch groups with the colors too

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I found some code that almost works for what i need, but i need it to copy the groups as well. Any ideas?

```
#target Illustrator  

var theFile = new 
File('C:/location/colors.ai');  

open(theFile,null);  


  var doc2 = app.activeDocument, doc = app.documents[1];  
  var thisSw, newSw;  
  for(var i=0; i<doc2.swatches.length; i++){  
    thisSw = doc2.swatches[i];  
    if(thisSw.name == "[Registration]" || thisSw.name == "[None]"){  
      continue;  
    }  
    newSw = doc.swatches.add();  
    newSw.name = thisSw.name;  
   newSw.color = thisSw.color;  
  };  
    doc2.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
```

Here is the original code for this as well  https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2285302 
I have tried changing swatches out for `swatchGroups`, but it only grabs the groups no colors. It did not understand how to fix that. I am not sure if there is a `var` i need to add for that or not.

Comment: What happens when it fails?

Comment: It only grabs the groups with out any of the colors/swatches

Comment: console.log(thisSw); and see what it is finding, just after you define it.

Comment: i know what it is finding. it is finding the group the swatches are grouped in but the what is in side of the group. It does copy the groups but not the swatches

Comment: You might want to paste-in some of your resulting data.

Comment: This web page is not best for uploading image. The best i can explain it is that i can move all of the swatches in to groups in adobe illustrator, but with the code above only move the swatches. If i change `swatches` out for `swatchGroups` it will only copy the group/folder but not swatches

Comment: I'm not sure how AI works, but you may need to copy the group first, the loop through and populate the swatches within it.

Comment: i figured something like that, but i am not a great coder my self and cant seem to find anything like this on line, so that is why I was asking. I am hoping some one can tell me a code loop or at least point me in the direct of one.

Comment: Click the image in the editor. You can upload images. Or link to an image and I can insert it until you have more rep